# Error using left join with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, left-join

I'm trying to do a left join in JPA 2.1, but I get an error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT new detail("+
        "TMB1004.numPosPiaReg, TMB1004.impRic,"+
        "TMB1006.prgPgt, TMB1006.prgPia, TMB1006.codCup, TMB1006.desTitPgt, TMB1006.impFinMinEse, TMB1006.impFinMinRim, TMB1006.impCofEntEse,"+
        "MFG1012.desReg, MFG1029.desPrv,"+ 
        "TEL1002.desEnt, TEL1002.codComEnt, TEL1002.codFisEnt,"+       
        "TEL1003.codNaz, TEL1003.codCinEur, TEL1003.codCinCnt, TEL1003.codAbi, TEL1003.codCab, TEL1003.codCnt, TEL1003.codTes, TEL1003.codCntTes,"+
        "TEL1004.numTelCtt, TEL1004.desIndEma,"+
        "TEL1005.desNomRef, TEL1005.desCogRef) "+         
        "FROM Tmb1004Piano TMB1004, Tmb1008Assoc TMB1008, Tmb1006Prog TMB1006 LEFT JOIN TEL1003 ON TMB1006.tel1003Ana.prgAnaCnb = TEL1003.prgAnaCnb, "+
        "Tel1002Ana TEL1002, Tel1003Ana TEL1003, Tel1004Ana TEL1004, Tel1005Ana TEL1005, "+
        "Mfg1012Regione MFG1012,"+ 
        "Mfg1029Provnuoist MFG1029 "+
        "WHERE TMB1006.tel1002Ana.codAnaEnt = TEL1002.codAnaEnt "+
        "AND TMB1006.prgPgt = TMB1008.tmb1006Prog.prgPgt "+
        "AND TMB1008.tmb1004Piano.prgPiaBei = TMB1004.prgPiaBei "+
        "AND TEL1005.prgAnaRef = TMB1006.tel1005Ana.prgAnaRef "+
        "AND TEL1004.prgAnaCtt = TMB1006.tel1004Ana.prgAnaCtt "+
        "AND MFG1012.codReg = TMB1004.codReg "+
        "AND MFG1029.codPrv = TMB1004.codPrv "+
        "AND TMB1006.tmb1003Tipo.id.prgTipSta != 1
```

The error I get is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 782 [SELECT DISTINCT new detail(TMB1004.numPosPiaReg, TMB1004.impRic,TMB1006.prgPgt, TMB1006.prgPia, TMB1006.codCup, TMB1006.desTitPgt, TMB1006.impFinMinEse, TMB1006.impFinMinRim, TMB1006.impCofEntEse,MFG1012.desReg, MFG1029.desPrv,TEL1002.desEnt, TEL1002.codComEnt, TEL1002.codFisEnt,TEL1003.codNaz, TEL1003.codCinEur, TEL1003.codCinCnt, TEL1003.codAbi, TEL1003.codCab, TEL1003.codCnt, TEL1003.codTes, TEL1003.codCntTes,TEL1004.numTelCtt, TEL1004.desIndEma,TEL1005.desNomRef, TEL1005.desCogRef) FROM Tmb1004Piano TMB1004, Tmb1008Assoc TMB1008, Tmb1006Prog TMB1006 LEFT JOIN TEL1003 ON TMB1006.tel1003Ana.prgAnaCnb = TEL1003.prgAnaCnb, Tel1002Ana TEL1002, Tel1003Ana TEL1003, Tel1004Ana TEL1004, Tel1005Ana TEL1005, Mfg1012Re MFG1012,Mfg1029Pr MFG1029 WHERE TMB1006.tel1002Ana.codAnaEnt = TEL1002.codAnaEnt AND TMB1006.prgPgt = TMB1008.tmb1006Prog.prgPgt AND TMB1008.tmb1004Piano.prgPiaBei = TMB1004.prgPiaBei AND TEL1005.prgAnaRef = TMB1006.tel1005Ana.prgAnaRef AND TEL1004.prgAnaCtt = TMB1006.tel1004Ana.prgAnaCtt AND MFG1012.codReg = TMB1004.codReg AND MFG1029.codPrv = TMB1004.codPrv AND TMB1006.tmb1003Tipo.id.prgTipSta != 1]

Why?

Comment: and column 782 of that statement is what??? You have the entities and database, so only you can see whether those columns and fields make sense

Comment: Can you make a simpler example please. By then, you'll probably have your syntax sorted out.